# Custom form in Outlook Task is not syncing

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

My partner and I created a custom task form to be used in Outlook using the developer mode to do that, and we published it to the Organization Forms Library for anyone to open. We're running into issues that I personally can't seem to find on how to resolve:

Custom forms aren't syncing correctly.

When I complete out the custom form, and I assign it to someone else they might be missing details like the dates I picked from the date picker, and text within the text box are gone too. It's very odd that sometimes some would get all the details that an end-user would input but that's like a 1/8 chance. I feel like there's a disconnect where it just won't behave like any other task. Cache mode or no cache mode doesn't matter it seems.  When the person assigns it back with changes made on their end, those changes aren't seen on my side. I just have the same original details that I made when I first made it. We're on Exchange Server 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a custom form was not published correctly to others in the organization. Try to create a new Outlook item on other machines with your custom forms to make sure they were deployed correctly.

Note, message forms default to separate layouts for composing and reading. Many people find their first message form doesn't look right when they receive an item created with it. That's simply because they forgot to click the Edit Read Page button and customize the Read layout!

You may find the [Customizing Outlook Message Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=61) article helpful.

Comment: Would there be a criteria that it was correctly deployed? Others can open the task form and fill in their own details and assign to others, but it's those inputs they make that do not get transferred over to the assigned person. Sometimes it just a mixed bag of missing inputs and having inputs for some reason. 

I don't think it's a matter of having the incorrect view either. If I input "Test" in one text box in that task form, the assigned person that I gave the task to does not see that word at all no matter which view they're in.

Comment: Did you associate a custom field with a corresponding user property?

Comment: See [Binding a Control to a Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/binding-a-control-to-a-field?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) .

Comment: I definitely have! Either I bind to an Outlook already-made field, or a create a new one of my own. For example, I would bind my due-date box to an actual due date field. One custom text box with a new field that I create by click on "new" from the Properties -> Value tab.